# Capistrano deploy a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I tried to deploy my Rails app, but I have some troubles because I have some folders in my repo git:

- Server

  - API (my rails app)
  - Test
- Hardware

How can I tell Capistrano that my rails app isn't in the `/` but is in `/Server/API` of the git folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution from following code, you can try it.

```
set :application, 'app_name'
set :repo_url, 'repo_url'
set :deploy_to, 'folder_name'
set :repo_tree, "app_name" (THIS line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

set :repo_tree, 'relative/path/from/your/repo'